# How to check if a word is a preposition (with regex in C)

Tags: c, regex

I read a text in C and i want to check if the current word is a preposition or not with regular expression

I have tried this but it didn't work

```
 int function(const char *testRegex){
     regex_t regex;

     if(regcomp(&regex, "^(a|an|the|in|on|of|and|is|are)$", 0)) {
            // handle error
     }
     int value;
     value = regexec(&regex, testRegex, 0, NULL, 0);
     return value;
  }
```

If i pass the function any word it always return that it didn't match even if i passed (a, an, the... )

so what is the problem ?

Comment: Please read this: [ask] and then [edit] and provide a [mcve] including actual vs. expected output. Also make up your mind about the language: C or C++.

Comment: Is that a POSIX regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"^(a|an|the|in|on|of|and|is|are)$"` is an extended regular expression: you should pass `REG_EXTENDED` to `regcomp`.

Also note that `regexec` returns `0` for a match and the `regex_t` object must be freed to avoid memory leaks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>

int isprep(const char *testRegex) {
    regex_t regex;
    int match;

    if (regcomp(&regex, "^(a|an|the|in|on|of|and|is|are)$", REG_EXTENDED)) {
        return -1;
    }
    match = !regexec(&regex, testRegex, 0, NULL, 0);
    regfree(&regex);
    return match;
}

int main() {
    printf("a -> %d\n", isprep("a"));
    printf("an -> %d\n", isprep("an"));
    printf("ann -> %d\n", isprep("ann"));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a -> 1
an -> 1
ann -> 0
```

Basic regular expressions require a `\` before the `(` to specify a subexpression and do not support alternations (`foo|bar`).

See more details in the [Open Group documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html).

Comment: I have tried that but it match each word i pass to the function

Comment: @MahmoudReda: I posted a complete example with 3 test cases.